# How to store text with HTML markup in xml?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have text with HTML markup I want to store in xml, to then be expressed through xsl.

I tried putting it in CDATA, but when expressing it it turns the markup in plaintext (with the <>s turned into escape characters).

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Please, share with us an example of your code

Comment: If the HTML happens to be XHTML (i.e it is also well-formed XML), then you could store it directly in the XML with the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml `.

Comment: @DMC19 So I pick the right example, what do you need it to clarify?